# Two Gates Active Simultaneously on the Same World

Tags: stargate

Related to questions:

- [Stargate Precedence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/why-does-earth-have-two-stargates)

Is it possible for two gates to be simultaneously active on the same world?

In the Stargate SG-1 episode Touchstone, it is revealed that the N.I.D. were using the second gate around the same time S.G. one were using theirs. Yet in episodes such as Stargate SG-1's Watergate, Stargate Command is unable to dial out due to another active wormhole.

Comment: @Thaddeus I don't think so.  This question is asking how those two gates could be used simultaneously, because one will always have priority over the other.  They were doing so, IIRC, because of some technobabble about it being detectable if the NID used their gate when the SGC's gate wasn't in use.  (Granted, I could be misremembering the events..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the episode SG1:S2-E14-Touchstone, the two gates were not "simultaneously active". One gate was utilized "a split-second" according to Captain Samantha Carter, **after** the first gate was closed in order to hide the signature of the second gate.

- The second gate, however, caused a spike in the power readings of the first gate as it was shut down. The closure of the first gate masked the existence of the second one.  (11:05)
- A tertiary backup log tracked the use of the second gate after the first one was closed. The gates are not active simultaneously, instead the wormhole is hijacked as the gate is closing allowing the connection to the location to remain open. (11:52)
- At 28:07 the SG1 team dial from Madrona and their wormhole signal is intercepted by the second stargate. The first stargate is NOT ACTIVE at the same time. The signal is traced to southern Utah.
- At 40:21, the General in charge of the SGC reports the gate will have an iris welded across the second gate and it will remain in the custody, under guard at the SGC. At 40:27 the scene shows the iris being welded into place over the second stargate.

Comment: I didn't pay close enough attention to that episode then.

Comment: Oh, so the offworld NID guys could actually dial Earth on a set schedule and when the SGC doesn't get a recognition code and closes the connection it would jump to the NIDs Stargate on Earth. But then if an SG team dialed home to evac just before a planned NID "wrong number" wouldn't that connection jump over when the SGC severs the connection? I'd think the NID would find Jaffa pouring out of their gate..